# Call a function after specified amount of time without changes to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Suppose you want to display an alert 3 seconds after there no changes in the DOM just after pressing a button that triggers a lot of changes.

An example with a button gotten via jQuery:

```
$someButton.on('click',function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    if( noChangesSinceLastTime()){
      time += 100;  
    }
    else{
      time = 0;
    } 

    if( time == 3000){
      alert("3 seconds without changes!");
    }

  },100);
});
```

Assume that the click event on that button has some other binding that excecutes a series of functions for DOM manipulation.

How could I achieve something as the `noChangesSinceLastTime()`function?

### More on my specific problem

I have an HTML+JS+CSS slideshow which works with many simultaneous clients in a network.

When a new client joins, he is automatically sent to the start of the current slide being watched by others.

What I want to do is that, just after it finishes loading the current slide, trigger the clicks necessary to sync the new client with others (since every click inside a slide triggers an animation step, and most slides have multiple steps).

I cannot add a callback in the JS slideware, since it's an obfuscated JS not made by me.

Comment: Here is reversed question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just pseudo code, but you could try something like this:

```
timer = setTimeout(function(){
   alert("3 seconds without changes!");
}, 3000);

if(/*some change happens*/) {
   clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar, with a `while` block instead of an `if`, but it resulted to be blocking code, thus not allowing for the DOM changes to finish.

Comment: @Sam while loop is blocking.

Comment: I see. I'll give a try with to your solution. Anyway, as far as I know, the /*some change happens*/ isn't trivial to detect.

I am taking a look at [mutation observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers) but I don't know if they will work out of the box in different browsers.

Comment: This worked very good, but my approach was wrong, since there were hidden changes to the DOM that continued for a while. What I finally did was something similar, but detecting only an specific change that always triggers just after the slide finishes loading. (In my case, the visibility of a "loading" visual feedback).

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to all of the [**DOM Mutatation** events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Common.2FW3C_events) and set a flag if any of those are were triggered.

Then in you interval function, you could check that flag and do whatever logic you want. =).

Regards,